# ==24303== Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation

Tags: c++, g++-4.7

Valgrind complains about the line with new (the first one):

```
     #ifndef MAXI_BUF_SIZE
     #define MAXI_BUF_SIZE 2*8192
     #endif

if (lg_maxi_buf == NULL)
{
      lg_maxi_buf = new unsigned char[MAXI_BUF_SIZE] ;
}
else
{
      delete [] lg_maxi_buf ;
      lg_maxi_buf = NULL ;
      lg_maxi_buf = new unsigned char[MAXI_BUF_SIZE] ;
}
```

I wanted to explain that the field `lg_maxi_buf` is part of class Audio_decoder and it is declared like this:

```
unsigned char *lg_maxi_buf;
```

in the constructor of the class Audio_decoder `lg_maxi_buf` is initialized in this way:

```
lg_maxi_buf = NULL;
```

Thanks for your answers. I think I will have to use smart pointers, but my knowledge on them is very poor.

Comment: This is not the real valgrind error, it's just a note explaining why the value is uninitialized. There is another error telling you that the result of the `if` condition depends on an uninitialized variable. Also, please consider using smart pointers.

Comment: Where was `lg_maxi_buf` initialized?

Comment: Not answer, but this condition don't need (you can leave code only from else block), because delete[] safe when argument is nullptr.

Answer (score 0):

you could simplify your if-else in

```
delete [] lg_maxi_buf ;
lg_maxi_buf = new unsigned char[MAXI_BUF_SIZE] ;
```

The delete operator ignores NULL parameters (you avoid many `if`s that way.
I personally don't affect NULL prior a new, but I understand if you prefer.

To initialize this bloc of memory, just add parenthesis:

```
lg_maxi_buf = new unsigned char[MAXI_BUF_SIZE]();
```